# Javax UriBuilder error

Tags: java, jersey, jetty, uribuilder

I have a Java application deployed on Jetty server, and I am using Jersey. Once I try to open the URL, I recieve an HTTP 500 error with the following message. I have read other posts regarding this error, saying that the problem is caused by multiple versions of Jersey and having two `UriBuilder` classes, but I have one version of `UriBuilder` class and the same version of Jersey.

```
 java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.uri(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder;
        at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:119)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:649)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:841)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:543)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1593)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1239)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:481)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1562)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:513)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:564)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:258)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$3.succeeded(SslConnection.java:147)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

here are my dependencies from gradle :

```
sourceCompatibility = 1.6
targetCompatibility = 1.6

repositories {
    maven { url("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/") }
    mavenCentral()
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/") }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies { classpath 'com.netflix.nebula:gradle-ospackage-plugin:1.9.2' }
}

ext.jerseyVersion='1.17.1'
ext.jettyVersion='9.4.3.v20170317'
ext.glassfishVersion='2.9.1'

dependencies {
    compile "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0"

    compile "com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:${jerseyVersion}"
    compile "com.sun.jersey:jersey-grizzly2:${jerseyVersion}"
    compile "com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:${jerseyVersion}"
    compile "com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:${jerseyVersion}"
    compile "com.sun.jersey:jersey-servlet:${jerseyVersion}"

    compile "com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-multipart:${jerseyVersion}"
    compile "com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-spring:${jerseyVersion}"

    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'

    compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'

    compile 'javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:1.1.1'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.10'

    testCompile group: 'org.jmock', name: 'jmock-junit4', version: '2.6.0'

    testCompile group: 'org.jmock', name: 'jmock-legacy', version: '2.6.0'

    testCompile group: 'cglib', name: 'cglib-nodep', version: '2.1_3'

    testCompile group: 'org.objenesis', name: 'objenesis', version: '1.0'

    testCompile group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest-core', version: '1.3'

    testCompile group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest-library', version: '1.3'

    compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'

    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.2'

    compile 'org.clojure:clojure:1.6.0'

    compile "org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:${jettyVersion}"
    compile "org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:${jettyVersion}"
    compile "org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:${jettyVersion}"

    compile 'org.freemarker:freemarker:2.3.20'

    compile "org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:${glassfishVersion}"
    compile "org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-grizzly2-servlet:${glassfishVersion}"
    compile "org.glassfish.jersey.connectors:jersey-grizzly-connector:${glassfishVersion}"
    compile 'com.hazelcast:hazelcast:2.6'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:3.2.1.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-core:3.2.1.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-web:3.2.1.RELEASE'

    compile 'org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.12'
    compile 'org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:2.2.1'

}
```

Comment: Probably just a mismatched version of your ws dependencies.  Can you list your runtime dependencies / jars?

Comment: Most likely the version of the Jetty library you have in your development environment is different from the one installed in your deployment server.  In your IDE the method is concrete, but in the server it is abstract.

Comment: The [`uri(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html#uri-java.lang.String-) method was added in JAX-RS 2.0. Seems you Jersey version is not JAX-RS 2.0.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt I added the dependencies to the post

Comment: Why do you have both Jersey 1.x and Jersey 1.x dependencies in your project? Choose one and remove the other. Remove everything org.glassfish.jersey

Comment: I mean Jersey 1.x and Jersey 2.x

Comment: @PaulSamsotha because they don't exist in 1.17.1 version

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what yo mean. In your post you said that you don't have two different versions of Jersey, but you do. com.sun.jersey is Jersey 1.x and og.glassfish.jersey is Jersey 2.x These are don't play well together. Use one or the other. Remove whatever one you don't use.